# What actions are considered as changing the creation of Allah?

Tags: tafseer, creation, surat-an-nisa

In [Surat An-Nisā'](http://quran.com/4), [ayah 119](http://quran.com/4/119), Allah says;

[image: Surat An-Nisa - 119]

> **Sahih International**
>  And I will mislead them, and I will arouse in them
>   [sinful] desires, and I will command them so they will slit the ears
>   of cattle, and I will command them so they will change the creation of
>   Allah ." And whoever takes Satan as an ally instead of Allah has
>   certainly sustained a clear loss.

According to this ayah, Satan will command us so we will change the creation of Allah. What is considered as changing the creation of Allah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comparison with 30:30 will show clearly that by "Allah's creation" is meant the religion of Allah, because the true religion is also the natural religion of man or the fitrah i.e. Islam.

> So direct your face toward the religion, inclining to truth. [Adhere to] the fitrah of Allah upon which He has created [all] people. **No change should there be in the creation of Allah.** That is the correct religion, but most of the people do not know. (Quran 30:30)

Answer (score 1):

There are tafsir which state that [Qur'an 4:119](https://quran.com/4/119) (*I will command them so they will change the creation of Allah*) is talking about Islam, the religion:

> And surely I will command them and they will change God’s creation’ substituting His religion with unbelief making lawful what God has made unlawful and making unlawful what God has made lawful.
> <sub>[Tafsir al-Jalalayn](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=74&tSoraNo=4&tAyahNo=119&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2)</sub>
>
> (and surely I will command them and they will change Allah's creation) Allah's Religion
> <sub>[Tanwîr al-Miqbâs min Tafsîr Ibn ‘Abbâs](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=73&tSoraNo=4&tAyahNo=119&tDisplay=yes&UserProfile=0&LanguageId=2)</sub>

However, along with Qur'an [30:30](https://quran.com/30/30) (*No change should there be in the creation of Allah. That is the correct religion, but most of the people do not know.*), Qur'an [55:3](https://quran.com/55/3), [25:24](https://quran.com/25/54), and [96:1-2](https://quran.com/96/1-2) says He *created man*, and Qur'an [3:190](https://quran.com/3/190), [29:61](https://quran.com/29/61), [43:9](https://quran.com/43/9), [14:32](https://quran.com/14/32), and [31:10-11](https://quran.com/31/10-11) says He *created the heavens and the Earth* (and [67:3](https://quran.com/67/3) says He created *seven heavens in layers.*).  There's other usages of the word "creates" ([خلق](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%AE%D9%84%D9%82)) in the Qur'an: [26:166](https://quran.com/26/166) (*And leave what your Lord has created for you as mates?*), [113:2](https://quran.com/113/2) (*the evil of that which He created*), and [16:81](https://quran.com/16/81).

In short, *All [things] are from Allah* ([Qur'an 4:78](https://quran.com/4/78)).  We can expect [Qur'an 4:119](https://quran.com/4/119) to be applicable more broadly, particularly to man (and possibly to the heavens and Earth).

Ahadith talk about changing the creation of Allah (in the sense of "man"), notably:

> Allah has cursed those women who practise tattooing and those who get themselves tattooed, and those who remove their face hairs, and those who create a space between their teeth artificially to look beautiful, and such women as change the features created by Allah.  ...
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 5931](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/146) (also [Sunan an-Nasa'i 5108](https://sunnah.com/nasai/48/69) [grade: sahih])</sub>

This is probably why, in addition to changing the religion, **there is also a focus on changing the human body**.  Many Fatawa apply [Qur'an 4:119](https://quran.com/4/119) in declaring changing various things relating to the human body haram: e.g. vasectomies ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=86967)), cosmetic surgery ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=87848); [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/97651)), hair transplantation ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=259948)) and hair removal ([Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/9037)), the use of solariums ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=6291)), botox ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=91870)), tattooing and branding animals' faces ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=85618)), tongue piercing ([IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=85912)), and sex-change operations ([Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/21277)).