# Can males pluck their eyebrows?

Tags: halal-haram, men, human-body

The Hadith which refers to the one plucking eyebrows being cursed is to females so can males pluck them? (Mine have a few long hairs and it would be nicer to remove these longer ones to look tidy. Some are thicker hairs which stand out on close inspection).

Answer (score 1):

**It is Haraam for men to pluck their eyebrows.**

From fatwa of Shaykh Abdul Azeez ibn Baaz rahamatullah alaihi we can say, plucking of eyebrows is not allowed, whether for men or women.

Check fatwa of Sheikh Muhammed Salih Al-Munajjid for more details: https://islamqa.info/en/3928

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**: Fatawa mostly describe men plucking eyebrows as forbidden, derived primarily from the hadith for women and arguing that it's "changing the creation of Allah".

---

Scholars (see below) tend to apply the ruling for women also to men:

> ... Allah has cursed those women who ... remove their face hairs ...
> <sub>[Sahih al-Bukhari 5931](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/146); see also [Sahih al-Bukhari 5939](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/154), [Sahih al-Bukhari 5943](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/158) and [Sahih al-Bukhari 5948](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/77/164)</sub>

Variations of this hadith are reported in [Sahih Muslim 2125 a](https://sunnah.com/muslim/37/181), [Jami` at-Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/urn/630040), [Riyad as-Salihin](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1646), [Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/urn/1263080), and [Sunan Abi Dawud 4169](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/35/11).  These are generally interpreted as applying only to eyebrow hair (see e.g. [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/13744)).

Precisely *why* eyebrow plucking is forbidden for women is not clear, and there's a range of opinions as to when it applies (see my answer to [Why is plucking the eyebrow haram?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/31007/17163)).  Thus, it's also not obvious as whether the same reasoning can be applied to men.  In fact, the reasoning is additionally unclear for men, since other reliable ahadith encourage men to shave their moustache and pluck their armpit hair, e.g.:

> Five are the acts of fitra: circumcision, removing the pubes, clipping the moustache, cutting the nails, plucking the hair under the armpits.
> <sub>[Sahih Muslim 257b](https://sunnah.com/muslim/2/65)</sub>

Several fatawa declare men plucking eyebrows is haram:

> It is not permissible for men, just as it is not permissible for women, to trim their eyebrows. Islam forbids plucking even one hair, and trimming could affect every hair, which is worse.
> <sub>Islam Q&A, fatwa [3928](https://islamqa.info/en/3928): *Men trimming their eyebrows*</sub>
>
> Namas is haraam for both men and women, because it is changing the creation of Allaah, and there is no difference between men and women in this case.
> <sub>Islam Q&A, fatwa [98477](https://islamqa.info/en/98477): *Ruling on a man plucking hair from his forehead and between the eyebrows*</sub>

Other similar fatawa are by [AskImam](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/31319) (*In principle, it is impermissible for both men and women to trim or shape their eyebrows*) and [MutfiSays](http://www.muftisays.com/qa/question/2720/plucking-you-eyebrows-.html) (*No, men are not allowed to pluck, trim or shave their eyebrows*).  So it seems the normal scholarly stance is that men plucking eyebrows is forbidden.

However, one fatwa expresses skepticism about this kind of ruling:

> Yes, one could possibly argue that the hadith mentions “changing the creation of Allah” and thus the ‘illah should be tagyīr khalqIllah or changing the creation of Allah, as was the opinion of Hafiz ibn Hajar and others. To this end our response would be that the statement “changing the creation of Allah” refers specifically to “those who split their front teeth seeking thereby adornment” as hinted to by Imam Nawawi in his Sharh Sahih Muslim. In addition, if we were to assume that removal of facial hair is haram since it is tantamount to “changing the creation of Allah”, then we’ll have to consider the shaving of the moustache for the male also as haram for the very same reason, an opinion that probably no scholar ever held.
> <sub>Shafi'i Fiqh, sourced from [IslamQA.org](https://islamqa.org/shafii/shafiifiqh/30085)</sub>

It also seems to conflict with another Islam Q&A fatwa:

> Whatever has not been mentioned in the teachings is pardoned. That includes hair of the nose, chest, back, legs and forearms.
> <sub>Islam Q&A, fatwa [221496](https://islamqa.info/en/221496): *Is it permissible for him to remove his body hair with a laser? Will that affect his fast?*</sub>

Nevertheless, a cautious approach would be for men to not pluck their eyebrows.

Answer (score -2):

no, as it is an organ given by Allah subhanahu ta'ala. it is the amanat for him.
and he must asked for this

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Answers here should be elaborate, and focused on addressing the question. Claims should be supported by evidence. Please visit our [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help), and refer to [how to answer questions](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hairs and eyebrows are not Organ. Yes it is a part of body like your nails. As cutting nails are allowed. There is several ruling for hair of different parts of our body, shaving some are allowed, some are forbidden and cutting to a certain length is ordered for some hair. Even there is different ruling for men and women and shaving hair of private parts are obligatory after certain time.